# How multiple dispatch violates encapsulation in c++

Tags: c++, encapsulation

1.Could anyone explain how multiple dispatch violates encapsulation (using C++) ?

I was reading scott meyers item31 where he says "We’ve pretty much bidden adios to encapsulation, because each collide function must be aware of each of its sibling classes, i.e., those classes that inherit from GameObject."

If a class A has multiple dependencies with other classes say B,C,D etc , still it would access the data only through interfaces of other classes. How will this violate class encapsulation ? In some text, I also read multiple dispatch, violates object based encapsulation. What is object based encapsulation? ( Could anyone explain what this means in c++). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

What Meyers is saying is that the fact that a class must know about another class, which it would otherwise not need to know about, is loss of encapsulation. It has to know about the siblings in order to implement the collide function. If we had achieved encapsulation none of the siblings would need to know about any other sibling classes.